# Compiling GINA.dll for 64bit errors

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, gina

while developing a custom windows GINA.DLL for a project it happen that is need to build it with for both platforms 32bit and 64bit 
after develop and testing for 32bit and code works great i tried to build it for 64bit platforms and it generated the following error :

```
Error   7   error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    3   Gina
Error   8   error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    3   Gina
Error   9   error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    3   Gina
Error   10  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxActivateUserShell'    d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    3   Gina
Error   11  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    3   Gina
Error   12  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    4   Gina
Error   13  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    4   Gina
Error   14  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    4   Gina
Error   15  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxDisplayLockedNotice'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    4   Gina
Error   16  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    4   Gina
Error   17  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    5   Gina
Error   18  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    5   Gina
Error   19  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    5   Gina
Error   20  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxDisplaySASNotice' d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    5   Gina
Error   21  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    5   Gina
Error   22  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    6   Gina
Error   23  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    6   Gina
Error   24  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    6   Gina
Error   25  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxGetConsoleSwitchCredentials'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    6   Gina
Error   26  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    6   Gina
Error   27  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    7   Gina
Error   28  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    7   Gina
Error   29  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    7   Gina
Error   30  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxGetStatusMessage' d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    7   Gina
Error   31  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    7   Gina
Error   32  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    8   Gina
Error   33  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    8   Gina
Error   34  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    8   Gina
Error   35  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxIsLockOk' d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    8   Gina
Error   36  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    8   Gina
Error   37  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    9   Gina
Error   38  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    9   Gina
Error   39  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    9   Gina
Error   40  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxIsLogoffOk'   d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    9   Gina
Error   41  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    9   Gina
Error   42  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    10  Gina
Error   43  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    10  Gina
Error   44  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    10  Gina
Error   45  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxLoggedOnSAS'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    10  Gina
Error   46  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    10  Gina
Error   47  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    11  Gina
Error   48  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    11  Gina
Error   49  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    11  Gina
Error   50  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxLoggedOutSAS' d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    11  Gina
Error   51  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    11  Gina
Error   52  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    12  Gina
Error   53  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    12  Gina
Error   54  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    12  Gina
Error   55  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxLogoff'   d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    12  Gina
Error   56  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    12  Gina
Error   57  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    13  Gina
Error   58  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    13  Gina
Error   59  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    13  Gina
Error   60  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxNetworkProviderLoad'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    13  Gina
Error   61  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    13  Gina
Error   62  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    14  Gina
Error   63  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    14  Gina
Error   64  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    14  Gina
Error   65  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxRemoveStatusMessage'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    14  Gina
Error   66  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    14  Gina
Error   67  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    15  Gina
Error   68  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    15  Gina
Error   69  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    15  Gina
Error   70  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxScreenSaverNotify'    d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    15  Gina
Error   71  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    15  Gina
Error   72  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    16  Gina
Error   73  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    16  Gina
Error   74  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    16  Gina
Error   75  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxShutdown' d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    16  Gina
Error   76  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    16  Gina
Error   77  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    17  Gina
Error   78  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    17  Gina
Error   79  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    17  Gina
Error   80  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxStartApplication' d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    17  Gina
Error   81  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    17  Gina
Error   82  error C2485: 'naked' : unrecognized extended attribute  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    18  Gina
Error   83  error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '_asm' keyword not supported on this architecture d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    18  Gina
Error   84  error C2065: 'jmp' : undeclared identifier  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    18  Gina
Error   85  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'RealWlxWkstaLockedSAS'   d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    18  Gina
Error   86  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  d:\projects\prostick\prostick\gina\Trampulim.cpp    18  Gina
```

i think the problem is in this code in two places "naked" and the inline assembly jump statement :

```
#define IMPLEMENT_TRAMPULIM_PROC(ProcName)      \
void* Real##ProcName = 0;                       \
extern "C" int __declspec(naked) ProcName(void) \
{                                               \
    _asm jmp Real##ProcName                     \
}                                               \
```

i posted the 2 files that contain this code in here :
https://gist.github.com/emad-elsaid/cca68983951c82eb8e60

i use visual studio 2008 professional edition

please note that i didn't write most of this code i copied it from a website that i don't remember unfortunately.
and as i don't have a large experience with windows programming with C++ i couldn't trace the error further.

Comment: With only six months of Windows XP/2003 support left to go, is it really worth the effort?

Comment: unfortunately in Egypt there is a high probability that my software user will use XP or windows7, so yes i have to do it :/

Comment: Note that GINA doesn't work at all on Windows Vista or later.

Comment: yes i'm aware of that Harry.

Answer (score 1):

The 64-bit version of MS Visual Studio compiler doesn't support inline assembler.

Without understanding WHY you are trampolining, it's hard to say what you should do instead (if anything).

Comment: i updated the gist with 2 more files that will ullustrated what are the functions defined in Trampulim.h do, please check the Gist again.

Comment: I thought that if you did a `declspec(__dllimport) void foo();` it makes a thunk (jump to `foo`). Now your code also translated X to RealX, but you could easily avoid that with a bit of macro work.

Comment: i need more tip Mats :), as you know i should execute the original MSGINA.DLL functions that i didn't implement in my GINA.DLL, so this is the way to do it right ? or am i lost here ?

Comment: I have to admit that I have no idea what GINA does, or how it works. So I can't help you on that.

Comment: Rather than trampolining, just create wrapper functions which explicitly call through to the original GINA.  These functions aren't called often enough for performance to matter.